# How to find out a user is logout or not in Facebook iFrame App?

Tags: facebook, logout, facebook-iframe

My application is iFrame App.  Before, I can use $_REQUEST['fb_sig_logged_out_facebook']  to determine the facebook user is logout or not.  However, with iFrame, I don't see that variable passing in.  What can I do?

I'm also using the new PHP SDK but it doesn't have any function to help me on that.

What I want to find out is whether the user has logged out facebook or not installed the application.  Both will return null in the facebook->session.  I need to distinguish these two. :)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook no longer provides that querystring value with the new authentication system. Facebook's migration guide states that you can "Assumed when there is not a profile_id and your application is an IFrame app." You can read more about the new canvas authentication here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/canvas

The other alternative is to check if the window.top.location is on the apps.facebook.com domain.

Comment: I have already tried. But the data returned by Logout user, and facebook Login but non-installed user is the same.

Comment: How about checking the window.top.location in javascript?

Comment: Unfortunately. Can't.  window.top.location is not accessible.

Comment: How so? Any iframe using javascript should be able to read that property.

Comment: facebook screen it out.  even i can access this, i can't tell whether or not the uer is logged out or logged in but not install the application. :)

Comment: Is your application an FBML application? FBML is not the same as an iFrame app. I can tell you for certain that if you are using an iframe app you can use the window.top property. In fact, facebook has this in many of their samples and documents.

Comment: Also, if you are building a new FBML app, you may want to think twice about that. Facebook is phasing out support for FBML apps.